# Laravel Mysql General Error 2014 with SELECT in CASE Statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a nested set data model, based on the [article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). I am storing posts and its comments in hierarchical manner. I need to get all latest posts and comments to show in user feed. When a comment is fetched for the feed, the entire path till the parent post is to be fetched.

I have written a query with SELECT in CASE statement. It is working fine on my local environment:
OS - OS X 10.10.5
PHP - 5.6.22 
MySQL - 5.7.12

But, gives me **MySQL General Error 2014** on the development/production server: 
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
PHP - 5.5.9
MySQL - 5.5.0

My Query is:

```
$sq = "CASE WHEN posts.content_type='post' THEN '1' ELSE ("
        . " SELECT json_array(parent.id,parent.title,"
        . " parent.slug,parent.description)"
        . " FROM posts AS parent, posts AS node"
        . " WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt"
        . " AND node.id = posts.id)"
        . " END as data";

$result = Post::where('deleted_at','NULL')
          ->where('is_approved','1')
          ->whereIn('user_id',[951,770,932])
          ->orWhereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(1,category_id)>0')
          ->orWhereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(2,category_id)>0')
          ->orWhereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(3,category_id)>0')
          ->orWhereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(7,category_id)>0')
          ->orWhereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(9,category_id)>0')
          ->select('*',DB::raw($sq))
          ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
          ->skip(0)
          ->take(10)
          ->get();
```